# Definition of Limit Superior of a sequence. Math Analysis 2nd ed. - Apostol

Tags: sequences-and-series

In Mathematical Analysis 2nd ed. by Apostol, at page 184, I find the notion of $\limsup$ of a sequence. Mr Apostol describes two conditions.

1. $\forall\epsilon>0\;\exists\text{ an integer }N\colon n>N \implies a_n<U+\epsilon$
2. Given $\epsilon,m>0\;\exists\text{ an integer } n>m\colon a_{n}>U-\epsilon$

If I look at $\sin(3n)$, I deduce that for $n>N$ $$a_{n}<U-\epsilon$$ and my first condition is satisfied.

I also deduce that for $n>m$ (starting from a certain $m$) $a_{n}\ngtr U-\epsilon$.

So my first question is:

Does this happen because the sequence oscillates? Should I infer that the $\limsup$ does not exist? Can I interpret the second condition in the following way?

$$\forall\epsilon,m>0\;\exists\text{ an integer } n>m\colon\text{ infinitely many } a_{n}>U-\epsilon$$

Thank you in advance.

[image: Sin(3n)]

Comment: All sequences have a limsup and a liminf.  These just might not be finite.  Look at the definition; both come from a limit of a monotone sequence.

Comment: Rather $$\forall \epsilon>0\;\exists\text{ infinitely many }n\colon a_n>U-\epsilon$$

Comment: @Hagen Is the "m" irrelevant in the second condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also deduce that for $n>m$ (starting from a certain $m$) $a_{n}\ngtr
>  U-\epsilon$.

Careful here, for condition 2 you just need that for a certain $m$ there is *some* larger $n$ such that $a_n > U-\epsilon$.

> $ii)\;\;\;\;\forall\;\epsilon,m>0\;\exists\; \text{an integer }
>  n>m\,\colon\, \text{infinitely many}\, a_{n}>U-\epsilon$

This is equivalent to the above: Certainly finitely many such $n$ can't suffice as you could just choose $m$ bigger than the greatest of them.

If you work with sequences the definition

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n := \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\sup_{m\geq n}x_m\Big)$$

might be more straight forward to use.

Comment: So in $Sin(3n)$ I have infinitely many $a_n$, with $n>m$ such that $a_n>1-\epsilon$. Considering our discussion, can I say that the $\limsup Sin(3n)=1$?

Comment: @Charlie Yes thats right.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was said in the comment, LimSup is a limit point of the sequence, and it always exists, either as a Real value, or it can take the value $\infty$. This is because the sequence of values is monotone and non-decreasing, so that it must either converge, if the sequence is bounded --and converge to the LUB of the sequence --or the sequence must go to $\infty$ if the sequence is unbounded.

Notice that LimSup is not just *a* limit point , but it is the largest limit point of the sequence. In the case of $Sin(3n)$, $LimSup(Sin(3n))=1$ , but notice that since $Sin(3n)\leq 1$, this is a "1-sided limit", since the sequence is bounded above, so only one of the inequalities holds.